# ERD - How to add an attribute to one side of the recursive relation?

Tags: erd

The simplified scenario for the ERD

- A company has employees (each has unique id `emp_id`)
- Each employee is supervised by another employee
- A supervising employee has a special attribute `SID`

Here is my ERD for the scenario and the the employee table. But the problem is every single employee who aren't supervisors will have an unnecessary column `SID` with `NULL`. I feel like there should be another table with `emp_id` and his/her `SID` to solve this. In order to do that how do I modify the ERD?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a simple case like this I would just leave the column as-is with the value NULL for non-supervisors.

For more complicated entities, look into *single table inheritance* which follows a pattern like:

```
Entity             SubType1
===========        ================
Id     (PK) <----  Id       (PK,FK)
SharedProp1   |    ST1SpecificProp1
SharedProp2   |    ST1SpecificProp2
SharedProp3   |    ...
...           |    
              |    SubType2
              |    ================
              `--  Id       (PK,FK)
                   ST2SpecificProp1
                   ...
```

All the common properties go in the base table, properties specific to a subtype (in your example the main type is person, the subtypes are supervisor and other).

There may also be a discriminator property in the shared table which states which subtype the current record it.

Many ORMs use this model to manage sub-types. Some DB systems have built-in support (IIRC postgres does via an optional module), but it is not difficult to put together yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You create a supervisor entity. It has the same identification as the employee. Each supervisor is an employee, an employee can be a supervisor.  In the data model, the supervisors' ID is a foreign key to the corresponding employee.